# How to install a Macbook Pro 2019 with ubuntu-21.10-desktop-amd64?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, macbook-pro

I'm attempting to perform the install (to an external USB-C spinning disk) described in the title.

It seems no matter what I try, I get a black screen shortly after attempting to boot from an external flash drive containing the Ubuntu installer.

I tried copying the .iso to my little USB flash drive using dd, baleenEtcher and UNetbootin on MacOS, as well as cp on Linux. I also tried converting the .iso to .img using:

```
hdiutil convert ubuntu-21.10-desktop-amd64.iso -format UDRW -o ubuntu-21.10-desktop-amd64.img
```

BTW, this resulted in a .img.dmg file, not a .img file, but I dd'd the .img.dmg anyway - to no avail.

I've tried erasing the flash drive before writing the installer.

I've tried using two different flash drives: one USB Type-A, one USB Type-C.  I tried the USB Type-A plugging into a dock, as well as directly to the macbook.  The USB Type-C I only tried plugged directly into the macbook.

With all of these attempts, I got a black screen when I tried to boot from the flash drive with the Ubuntu installer on it.

What do I need to do to get the installer to boot on this system?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you verify the ISO you downloaded? If you have a corrupted ISO, it doesn't matter how many different ways you try to flash it.  Have you searched/researched about how to boot a USB on this particular model computer?

Comment: The recent MacBook Pros are actively hostile to having non-Apple operating systems installed onto them. Even if you manage to get the base OS installed, you will struggle with a myriad of downstream problems involving incomplete drivers and a noticeable heat problem that leads to excessive throttling. If you plan on keeping macOS installed, you would be better off running Ubuntu in a VM rather than on bare-metal.

Comment: @Nmath Good thought, but I just tried the Type-A flash drive in a Dell and it booted right up into the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: @matigo I was afraid of that.  I actually tried VirtualBox, but got a tiny viewport that made it unusable for my purpose.  I also tried VMware Fusion, and while it came closer, it couldn't do my webcam well enough.